# How move character sword to parry enemy's attacks when blocking?

Tags: animation, unreal-engine4, game-development

I'm working on melee combat system. I don't know how start the block attacks animation. 
My combat system is inspired by The Witcher 3 combat system. My problem is how can I do the character move his sword to parry the enemy's attacks. My question is about visual aspect.
You could see an example video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bp8pW_LPnn0).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking to use an [IK setup](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Animation/IKSetups).
This will help to guide your weapon towards a certain point of impact such as another weapon or a shield. Here is a paper describing different melee combat techniques that can be used. [Link](https://assets.ctfassets.net/y4twieuxp19i/5WBm8ecHVC2EIQEGS26mMS/3435e9e01ffd7e57091597d67f7af7ca/ReactiveMeleeCombat.pdf)

Comment: Glad I could help!